# Missing delimiter (. inserted). error

Tags: errors, equations

I'm trying to type up a fairly annoying closed form, and I don't understand why it isn't letting me typeset it.

The equation is this:

```
$P_{n}=4\times\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\big{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor-1}}\times\bigg(2\bigg)^{\big{\frac{3-(-1)^{n}}{4}}}
```

When I place the `\big` command in the first index (when raising half to the power of the floor function), it works just fine. But when I do exactly the same to the next index, it returns the Missing delimiter (. inserted). error.

I tried looking into what that error means, but only seemed to be able to find answers specific to particular pieces of code. From what I gathered, the code is telling me that I need to put a `.` somewhere in order to nullify a delimiter, but I don't have any delimiters that need nullifying to my understanding; I need all of them!

Apologies for any un-neatness. This is only my second question and I'm still learning the `TeX` language.

Thanks for your time and patience,

Eliot.

Comment: It's most likely a missing right bracket (one tends to forget the right one rather in left-to-right writing ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty annoying indeed. But I'd use the slashed form for 1/2 and `\tfrac` for the fractions in the exponents. However, this needs some corrections, because the exponent would hide the base, without them. So I propose to raise the exponents by some amount. In order to fix also the alignment of the fraction numerators, a `\mathstrut` is used for `n+1` to compensate for the parentheses in `(-1)` in the other exponent. Finally, `\bigl` and `\bigr` are used for the floor parentheses because `\left` and `\right` would produce too big fences.

The auxiliary macro `\makehigher` pretends that the base is higher than its natural height by adding an invisible rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\makehigher}[2][3]{%
  {\rule{0pt}{#1ex}#2}%
}


\begin{document}
\[
P_{n}=4\cdot
\makehigher{(1/2)}^{\bigl\lfloor\tfrac{\mathstrut n+1}{2}\bigr\rfloor-1}\cdot
\makehigher{2}^{\tfrac{3-(-1)^{n}}{4}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Adjust the amount of raising (default 3ex) by using the optional argument; you could try `\makehigher[2.5]{...}`).

Here's a picture where I added also a rule to show that the fraction lines in the exponents are level with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The macro `\big` "expects" an opening or closing 'item', e.g, `( ) [ ] \{ \} \langle \rangle`. Writing `\big{...}` throws an error, as you've discovered.

However, from the comments you've posted, I understand that your objective is *not* to produce curly braces to surround the exponent but, rather, to enlarge the font size used in the exponent. Since first-level superscript (and subscript) material is set in `\scriptstyle` by default, you should specify `\textstyle` -- the next "math size" up from `\scriptstyle` -- at the start of the exponent material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac macro
\begin{document}
$P_{n}=4\times\biggl(\dfrac{1}{2}\biggr)^ {\textstyle \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor-1}
\times
\biggl(2\biggr)^{\textstyle\frac{3-(-1)^{n}}{4}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. However, I'm not intending on having the curly brackets around the indices. The reason I had \big{ insert stuff here that will be typeset bigger } is precisely for the reason inside those brackets. My problem essentially, is that left alone, the indices are far too small to read as they are a bit complex. I just wanted to make the indices bigger so that my tutor can read them, haha.

Comment: Tried that - makes it too big :/

Comment: Ah, perfect. That seemed to work. Thank you very much for your patience.